# How do I apply Movie Clip edits to my video sequence?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes, video, movie-clip-editor

I did some stabilization using the Movie Clip Editor and tracking. I understand that what I have done is just in memory. How do apply the changes I have made in the MCE to my strip in the Video Sequence Editor?

Comment: Render the stabilized clip as a new video element, and bring that one into the VSE

Comment: @cegaton Thanks for the response. Is there no way to apply the MCE changes to the VSE? I am stitching together several videos, and will have to do this several times.

Comment: Think about the Video Clip Editor/Compositor and the VSE as a disfunctional marriage. They live together, but they don't speak to each other.

Comment: OK. I can understand that. If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as correct, after I have gone through the process.

Comment: I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nU8zqn091rM rendered the video as you suggested, have no sound and the video is constantly zooming in and out very rapidly. It looks like an earthquake.

Comment: How did you use the stabilizer information on the compositor?

Comment: I used the Stabelize 2D node - I did make sure I pulled in the correct video in the node

Comment: Please ask as a new question. This is not a forum.

Comment: In the VSE a Movie Clip from the MCE can have its 2D stabilise effect turned on.